# Why does Redis show 2 clients connected when i run my spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, redis

I have a Spring boot project with angular 2 front end ,when i run spring boot project and turn on the Redis server,the Redis server shows 2 clients are connected to it.Why is that? It should be 1 client because only spring project is connecting to it.I am using Spring boot 2.3 and Redis version is 2.4

spring-

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableRedisHttpSession
  class RedisSessionConfig {
       @Bean
        public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            return new LettuceConnectionFactory(); 
        }

  }

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Autowired
    Environment env; 

    @Autowired
    UserSecurityService useSecurityService;
    
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
    }
    
    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATHCES= {
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/image/**",
            "/book/**",
            "/user/**"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(useSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATHCES).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and();
        http.csrf().disable()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
        
    }
     
      @Bean
      public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionStrategy() {
          return  HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
      }
            
}

@Configuration
public class RedisConfigureAction {
    @Bean
    public ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
        return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can execute the command `client list` to see which users are connected (address and port number)

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi i tried it,it shows 2 clients,i will edit the question and paste the image of the result of `client list`